# How can I write a regex to pick repeating patterns in php from a file

Tags: php, regex

With this string from a file with similar lines,

```
03/21/19 11:20 LOC3 UNA:
03/21/19 11:40 LOC2 IN: NEW BD     PN  VO    LVA
03/21/19 11:50 LOC3 OFF:
03/21/19 12:20 LOC2 IN: OLD XD     AB  VO    LVA
```

I need to capture the NEW, BD, PN, VO,LVA from lime 1, and OLD,XD,AB,VO,LVA  in line 2 and so on, ignoring the other lines

This only picks the last 'VO' term

```
IN:\s(([^\s]+)\s+)+.*LVA
```

Comment: What do you mean by repeating ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may *match* the occurrences of non-whitespace chunks of text after a specific text having some text further in the string using

```
preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!\A)(?=.*LVA)|IN:)\h+\K\S+~', $s, $matches)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SW4rBM/4)

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!\A)(?=.*LVA)|IN:)` - either the end of the previous match (that has `LVA` later in the string after 0+ chars other than line break chars) or  `IN:` substring (basically, it means *match consecutive substrings that meet the pattern after `IN:` but only if there is `LVA` later*)
- `\h+` - 1+ horizontal whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars.

[PHP](https://3v4l.org/Kibka):

```
$s = "03/21/19 11:20 LOC2 IN: NEW BD     PN  VO    LVA";
if (preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!\A)(?=.*LVA)|IN:)\h+\K\S+~', $s, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
// => Array ( [0] => NEW [1] => BD [2] => PN [3] => VO [4] => LVA )
```

To get multiple matches, wrap the pattern in the first non-capturing group with a capturing group and then check the submatches when building the final output. Something like

```
$s = "03/21/19 11:20 LOC2 IN: NEW BD     PN  VO    LVA
03/21/19 11:20 LOC2 IN: NEW BD     PN  VO    LVA VB";
$res = [];
if (preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!\A)(?=.*LVA)|(IN:))\h+\K\S+~', $s, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0)) {
    $tmp = [];
    foreach ($matches as $r) {
        if (count($r) > 1) {
            if (count($tmp)>0) {
                $res[] = $tmp;
                $tmp = [];
            }
        }
        $tmp[] = $r[0];
    }
    if (count($tmp)>0) {
        $res[] = $tmp;
    }
}
print_r($res);
// => Array (
//     [0] => Array ( [0] => NEW [1] => BD [2] => PN [3] => VO  [4] => A )
//     [1] => Array ( [0] => NEW [1] => BD [2] => PN [3] => VO  [4] => LVA )
// )
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/jN3MY).

Answer (score 0):

If the string always has the same pattern then you can use a budget solution by exploding on new line and `": "` and get the last value.

```
$str = "03/21/19 11:20 LOC2 IN: NEW BD     PN  VO    LVA
03/21/19 11:20 LOC2 IN: OLD XD     AB  VO    LVA";

foreach(explode("\n", $str) as $line){
    $tmp = explode(": ", $line);
    $result[] = end($tmp);
}

var_dump($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/IbfBo